# Get-ADGroupMember stopped working for some users

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Not sure when this started, but when I try to get the group membership with Get-ADGroupMember with an account that has administrative priviliages I get the below error:

```
Get-ADGroupMember : An operations error occurred
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADGroupMember -Identity redacted
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (redacted:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

If I try to expand the actual error it ends up being this:

```
PS C:\Users\redacted> $error[0] | select *


PSMessageDetails      :
Exception             : Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADException: An operations error occurred --->
                        System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[schemas.microsoft.com._2008._1.ActiveDirectory.CustomActions.GetADGroupMemberFault]:
                        Active Directory returned an error processing the operation.

                        Server stack trace:
                           at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
                           at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation,
                        Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
                           at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime
                        operation)
                           at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

                        Exception rethrown at [0]:
                           at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
                           at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
                           at
                        schemas.microsoft.com._2008._1.ActiveDirectory.CustomActions.AccountManagement.GetADGroupMember(GetADGroupMemberRequest
                        request)
                           at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.GetADGroupMember(GetADGroupMemberRequest request)
                           --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
                           at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.ThrowException(CustomActionFault caFault, FaultException
                        faultException)
                           at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.AdwsConnection.GetADGroupMember(GetADGroupMemberRequest request)
                           at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADWebServiceStoreAccess.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.IADAccountManagement.
                        GetADGroupMember(ADSessionHandle handle, GetADGroupMemberRequest request)
                           at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADAccountManagement.GetGroupMembers(String partitionDN, String groupDN, Boolean
                        recursive)
                           at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember.GetADGroupMemberProcessCSRoutine()
                           at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.CmdletSubroutinePipeline.Invoke()
                           at Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.ADCmdletBase`1.ProcessRecord()
TargetObject          : redacted
CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (redacted:ADGroup) [Get-ADGroupMember], ADException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
ErrorDetails          :
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
```

What's interesting is I cannot reproduce this in my development environment and it only happens when running under certain accounts (most notably those with accounts administration type rights).

What's funny is **Get-ADGroup -Identity redacted -Properties member** works just fine.  The thing is that I need to get the membership of a nested group and I'd really...really like to avoid re-inventing the wheel if I don't have to.

It seems like the problem is permissions related, but I really don't know where to start with it.  I've done some searching and found a few hits but nothing with a solution.

So....anyone have any thoughts or suggestions?

Comment: Can you show some of your code around the area this exception is thrown?

Comment: Reading nested memberships requires rights to read the "tokenGroupsGlobalAndUniversal" Attribute, which is readable, if the (reading) user is member of "Windows Authorization Access Group" of the target Domain. Might that group membership be missing?

Comment: @Caleb, not sure what you're looking for as there really isn't any code:

Get-ADGroupMember -Identity Groupname -Recursive

Comment: @TGlatzer,
The only things in my forest that are a member of that group are services\computers such as Exchange.  There are no users that are in that group so I don't think that is it as this AD cmdlet works fine from some accounts and not others and those where it does are not in that group.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 4):

In my case i get the exact same error when querying AD groups with Get-ADGroupMember if the group I query has members from trusted forests. All other groups work just fine, but when the cmdlet finds objects from outside the domain where it runs it throws the error. The workaround using Get-AdGroup and then expand the Members attribute and use that output in further commands works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same error as well when using [Get-ADGroupMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-adgroupmember?view=win10-ps) to perform Recursive Query.

```
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8224,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADGroupMember
```

at the end i found that [RODC](https://www.windows-active-directory.com/read-only-domain-controller.html) is the culprit and use this method solved the issue

```
$UList = get-adgroupmember -Server DontUseReadOnlyDomainController -Identity 'ADGroupName' -Recursive
foreach ($user in $UList)
{
    write-host $user.SamAccountName $user.distinguishedName
           
}
```

my environment consist of multiple domains with Domain trust